# Recommendations for contact form module with file attachments?

Tags: module, contact-form

I'm looking for an easy-to-configure contact form module which will accept file attachments and has email-to-admin functionality? Does anyone have any recommendations? There's a number of seemingly well-rated modules in the extensions directory, but I just thought I'd ask if anyone had experience with one that they found particularly good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Fox Contact](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fox-contact-form/)? It should do what you are looking for.

Edit: Please see [this link](http://www.fox.ra.it/forum/20-form-fields/9293-attachments-upload-button.html) as it contains some more information regarding the attachments/uploads.

Regards
D

Comment: That looks like a great module, but I was hoping for something free. Do you have experience with this module? I'm particularly interested if there's email with attachements functionality cooked in.

Comment: @nizz0k I have used it, not directly with file uploads myself though. I have edited my answer to include an additional link to some more information